# Visual Studio Error List Window Opens on Build

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this happen with certain projects; when I build the solution the error list window pops up right away even if there are no errors. I want the output window to show on build. I have these settings 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced same issue -- in my case narrowed it down to requireReinstallation="true" in my packages.config which had been (automatically?) inserted as a consequence of a retargeting to a newer framework.  Removal of requireReinstallation="true" attribute returned build output windows to normal.

Ref. "Project Retargeting and Upgrade Build Errors/Warnings" in 
http://blog.nuget.org/20130814/nuget-2.7-release-candidate.html

Comment: That is an awesome find. Thank you so much. Fixed my problem